# Does the "Expired - Lifetime" status of US patents allow all types of future use of the IP?

Tags: intellectual-property, patents

I recently found a patent that has expired this month after almost 20 years. The original inventor still has not done anything substantial with his idea, and frankly, it is a really cool and doable project for me and my team.

So I wanted to know. Are there any limitations of what can be done with an IP that has an expired patent? Like can I sell a product based on that idea without paying any dividends back to the original inventor?

Note: Not a duplicate of the linked question as that one mainly asked about how to ask permission for using an active patent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can patents for an invention expire? If so, how? If not, how can I get permission to borrow or buy it?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17409/can-patents-for-an-invention-expire-if-so-how-if-not-how-can-i-get-permissio)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question was about how to get permission to use a current patent, and mentioned expiration in the title but nowhere in the body of the question. It also did not ask about various kinds of use, as this question does. If closed as a duplicate, i would vote to reopen.